# Runtime error - 1035 - Teste de Seleção 1 - URI Online Judge

Tags: c#

Primeiramente, não tenho muita experiencia com C#, apenas sei lógica de programação. Estou estudando C# por curiosidade, é uma linguagem que sempre me interessou.

Estou estudando pelo URI e não estou conseguindo resolver esse exercício:

> Leia 4 valores inteiros A, B, C e D. A seguir, se B for maior do que C
>   e se D for maior do que A, e a soma de C com D for maior que a soma de
>   A e B e se C e D, ambos, forem positivos e se a variável A for par
>   escrever a mensagem "Valores aceitos", senão escrever "Valores nao
>   aceitos".

O código eu executo no Visual Studio e funciona corretamente, mas quando envio pro URI ele dá o erro:

> Runtime error

O código está assim:

```
using System; 

class URI {

    static void Main(string[] args) { 

            int a, b, c, d;

            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if ( (b > c) &&  (d > a) && ((c + d) > (a + b)) && (c > 0 && d > 0) && (a % 2 == 0)) {                
                Console.WriteLine("Valores aceitos");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Valores nao aceitos");
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Não cheguei a validar a lógica da condição... mas a console funcionou sem erros para mim, tanto em debug quanto na execução da release

Comment: Então, pra mim também funcionou. Só não entendo porque o URI não aceita o código

Comment: Ah, pode ser que eu tenha que criar um vetor para os valores de entrada, pensei nisso agora.

Comment: entendi, você quer passar os valores como argumento

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? @JulioCesar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um tratamento simples para caso os valores forem apresentados como argumentos para o programa, se não o input é feito pelo Console.Radline(). Outro detalhe, não é bom você não indicar um namespace para a sua aplicação.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class URI
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b, c, d;
            if (args.Length == 4)
            {
                a = int.Parse(args[0]);
                b = int.Parse(args[1]);
                c = int.Parse(args[2]);
                d = int.Parse(args[3]);
            }
            else
            {
                a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if ((b > c) && (d > a) && ((c + d) > (a + b)) && (c > 0 && d > 0) && (a % 2 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valores aceitos");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valores nao aceitos");
            }            
        }
    }
}
```